# Grab my applications form play store

Tags: android, android-activity, android-developer-api

I want to know if is there some way to grab my applications from play store?
in my current application I want to create activity `Our Projects` and this activity must display all applications under developer profile.
is there any `API` in `Play store service`?
thank you

Comment: you can  simply redirect the user to your developer page in a browser or play store just by using the URL of your play store developer profile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an intent for this, if you know the package name, you can start an intent to open PlayStore at that application:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName));
startActivity(intent);
```

But in this case you can get ActivityNotFoundException, when the PlayStore isn't installed on the phone, in this case you can open your app in browser:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + packageName));
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope it helps, and that's what you'd wanted to ask :)